# Concurrent Event Handlers have race conditions. How to fix fix them?

Tags: concurrency

Event handler E1 makes a long running network request.
Event handler E2 is very quick and doesn't make a network request. It writes to database.

E1 is guaranteed to start to execute before E2 however, E1 finishes after E2. How can I force that E2 always finishes after E1?

Thanks.

Comment: Need more context here. What part of E1 has to execute before what part of E2? Synchronize based on that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is it possible that you know how to _guarantee_ that E2 will not start until after E1 starts, but you do _not_ know how to guarantee that E2 will not end until after E1 ends?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention any language. I like Java, but you can find something like [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) in many languages and libraries.

```java
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);

void E1(...) {
    doSomeStuff();
    sem.release();
}

void E2(...) {
    doStuffThatsSafeToDoWhile_E1_StillIsDoingItsStuff();
    sem.acquire();
    doStuffThatMustWaitUntilAfter_E1_IsFinished();
}
```

This will work for *just one* pair of calls to `E1` and `E2`. I don't want to suggest any way to "reset" it to be used again and again. I'll leave that part up to you because I don't want to assume anything about the relationship between `E1` and `E2`. I don't know *why* there is stuff that must wait until E1 is finished. I don't know what "finished" really means. If `E1` and `E2` are allowed to be called again, I don't know what had to happen in order to allow it.

---

**Edit:**

Maybe, at a high level, you're really only handling one "event," but at a low-level, you get the notification of that event in two parts.

If so, then how about we do all of the work to handle the high-level event within one handler function, and let the other handler function do nothing except open a gate when it's safe for the first one to finish whatever needs to be finished?

```java
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);

void E1(...) {
    doStuffThatCanBeSafelyDoneBefore_E2_isCalled();
    sem.acquire();
    doStuffThatMustNotBeDoneUntilAfter_E2_isCalled();
}

void E2(...) {
    sem.release();
}
```